# Use Projections / Views as @RequestBody

Tags: spring-boot

I have recently learned about projections in Spring Boot and started to implement some like this one:

```java
public interface MenuCard {

    Long getId();

    @NotNull
    String getName();

    String getDescription();

}
```

Which works perfectly fine e.g. in the context of a repository:

```java
public interface MenuCardRepository extends JpaRepository<MenuCardEntity, Long> {
    Optional<MenuCard> getById(Long id);
}
```

However, my problems begin when I try to also accept a `MenuCard` as a `@RequestBody`:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = ROOT + "/menu-cards", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MenuCard createMenuCard(
        @PathVariable(name = "businessId") Long businessId,
        @Validated @RequestBody MenuCard menuCard
) {
    return this.menuCardService.create(businessId, menuCard);
}
```

It is rather obvious that this won't work:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: 
[simple type, class mahlzeit.server.hibernate.view.MenuCard]; 

nested exception is:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Cannot construct instance of `mahlzeit.server.hibernate.view.MenuCard` 
(no Creators, like default construct, exist)
```

The question is now:

What is the "easierst" and "fastest" way around this? Yes, I could just accept my `MenuCardEntity` (`@Entity`) object, **but** I am also generating code using Springfox. If I'd return `MenuCard` on on end, but accept `MenuCardEntity` at the other, it would end up in type-hell.

---

#### Note

Using `@JsonDeserialize(as = MenuCardEntity.class)` on `MenuCard` is obviously **not** an option